# How to Import other node packages in Angular 4 CLI projects

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm trying to import a [graphlib-dot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphlib-dot) package from npm in my angular 4/5 CLI project.

I added it to the angular-cli.json -> scripts: [../node_modles/.../graphlib-dot.min.js]

And i tried to declare var graphlib: any; in the top of my app.component.ts.

But still Angular doesn't recognize this "graphlib"...

Please help...

Comment: simply import in the `main.ts` file as `import * as graphlib from 'graphlib'`

Comment: try to do like this -  declare var graphlibDot: any;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add graphlib to  .angular-cli.json

```
 "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/graphlib-dot/dist/graphlib-dot.min.js"
  ],
```

then in the component

```
declare var graphlibDot: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {

 constructor() {
    console.log('graphlibDot', graphlibDot);
 }
}
```

Comment: I'm quite new to this area, could you give some tips on how to find correct declare name for a external npm js library ?  Thank You